# Moveit missing rosdep dependencies on raspbian jessie

Tags: moveit, rosdep, raspberrypi, debian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to install moveit on a raspbian.

First I installed ROS indigo using [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi). After that i followed [these manual instructions](http://moveit.ros.org/install/) to install moveit, but I could not install the dependencies.

```
$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "jade"
Add distro "kinetic"
updated cache in /home/pi/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
moveit_ros_benchmarks: No definition of [eigen_conversions] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_perception: No definition of [sensor_msgs] for OS [debian]
moveit_setup_assistant: No definition of [xacro] for OS [debian]
moveit_fake_controller_manager: No definition of [pluginlib] for OS [debian]
moveit_msgs: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS [debian]
moveit_planners_ompl: No definition of [pluginlib] for OS [debian]
moveit_controller_manager_example: No definition of [pluginlib] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_move_group: No definition of [pluginlib] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_planning: No definition of [angles] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_robot_interaction: No definition of [interactive_markers] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_control_interface: No definition of [trajectory_msgs] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_manipulation: No definition of [manipulation_msgs] for OS [debian]
moveit_commander: No definition of [python-pyassimp] for OS version [jessie]
moveit_simple_controller_manager: No definition of [actionlib] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_warehouse: No definition of [tf] for OS [debian]
moveit_core: No definition of [tf_conversions] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_visualization: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_planning_interface: No definition of [tf_conversions] for OS [debian]
```

I am new to ROS and this infrastructure, so its possible I missed something or did something wrong.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235549/moveit-missing-rosdep-dependencies-on-raspbian-jessie/) by [cmhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27017/cmhe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27017/cmhe/) on 2016-05-30**:
Could it be that this happens because the [rosdep indigo distribution definition](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml) does not mention debian jessie? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it myself. Here are my notes as to what I did. Maybe that will help someone in the future:

```
# Guide to get all moveit dependencies installed on raspbian jessie.
# Install ros as described here: wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi
# Install moveit as described here: http://moveit.ros.org/install/#collapseFour
# This manual describes how to get the line: "rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y" to work.

# Increase swap size:
$ sudo sed -i -e "s/CONF_SWAPSIZE=100/CONF_SWAPSIZE=1024/" /etc/dphys-swapfile
$ sudo reboot

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb-src http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse restricted

# Lower priority for ubuntu packages
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/ros-trusty 
Package: *
Pin: release o=ROS,a=trusty
Pin-Priority: 50

# Get 0.2 version of urdfdom from ubuntu source repo. Specify exact available version or deactivate deb-src from jessie beforehand
$ apt-get source -b 'urdfdom'
$ sudo dpkg -i liburdfdom0.2-dbg_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-dev_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-model0.2_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-model-state0.2_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-sensor0.2_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-tools_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb liburdfdom-world0.2_0.2.10+dfsg-1_armhf.deb

# ros-indigo-pluginlib searches for 'liblog4cxx.so' in '/usr/lib'
# liblog4cxx10-dev is installed
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblog4cxx.so /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so

# Install all dependencies as ubuntu:trusty (in moveit directory)
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --os=ubuntu:trusty

# Now we have installed every package required by moveit, but they are compiled for ubuntu trusty.
# Everything might work for raspbian jessie (debian jessie) too, but to be sure, I compiled every package myself in the next steps.

# Find all installed packages from trusty, that are not in jessie.
$ aptitude search -F '%p' '?narrow(?installed,?narrow(?archive(trusty),?not(?archive(jessie))))' > trusty-packages
# Remove all trusty packages:
$ cat trusty-packages | xargs sudo apt-get remove --purge -y

# Install build dependencies, that are not already mentioned in trusty-packages (and don't start with "ros-"):
$ sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev libmongo-client-dev

# Install python module for sorting package dep order
$ sudo apt-get install python-toposort

# Small python script to order the packages with their dependencies:
$ cat depsort.py
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys
from toposort import toposort_flatten
graph={}
for line in sys.stdin:
    if len(line.split()) == 2:
        a,b = line.split()[0], line.split()[1]
    elif len(line.split()) == 1:
        a,b = line.split()[0], None
    else:
        raise Exception, "Invalid input! Line: \"%s\"" % line
    if a not in graph:
        graph[a] = {b}
    else:
        graph[a].add(b)
for line in toposort_flatten(graph):
    if line != None:
        print line

# Generate sorted package list:
$ cat trusty-packages | while read pkg
    do
      echo $pkg
      for i in $(apt-cache showsrc "$pkg" | grep '^Build-Depends:' | grep -oE "ros-[-a-z0-9]*")
        do
          echo $pkg $i
        done
      for i in $(apt-cache show "$pkg" | grep '^Depends:' | grep -oE "ros-[-a-z0-9]*")
        do
          echo $pkg $i
        done
    done | ./depsort.py > sorted-trusty-packages

# Filter out installed packages (if something goes wrong when building/installing and you like to continue where you left off)
# Because ros-indigo-rviz needs a patch to build, leave it out for now.
$ cat sorted-trusty-packages | while read pkg
    do
      if [ "$pkg" != "ros-indigo-rviz" ]
      then
        dpkg -s $pkg 2>&1 | grep -E "^Status:.*installed" >/dev/null || echo $pkg
      fi
    done > filtered-sorted-trusty-packages

# Build packages and install them:
$ cat filtered-sorted-trusty-packages | while read pkg
  do
    echo "####Building: $pkg"
    apt-get source -b $pkg
    echo "####Installing: $pkg"
    sudo dpkg -i "$pkg"*"deb"
  done 2>&1 | tee -a build.log

# ros-indigo-rviz cannot be build

# get it:
$ apt-get source ros-indigo-rviz
$ cd ros-indigo-rviz-1.11.14

# Apply this patch:
--- ros-indigo-rviz-1.11.14.orig/src/rviz/mesh_loader.cpp
+++ ros-indigo-rviz-1.11.14/src/rviz/mesh_loader.cpp
@@ -67,6 +67,14 @@
 #include <assimp/IOSystem.h>
 #endif
 
+#  ifdef __arm__                 // fix for ARM build
+#include <strings.h>
+bool Assimp::IOSystem::ComparePaths(const char *p1, const char *p2) const
+{
+    return !::strcasecmp(p1, p2);
+}   
+#  endif
+
 namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
 
 namespace rviz

$ dpkg-source --commit

$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
$ sudo dpkg -i ../ros-indigo-rviz_1.11.14-0trusty_armhf.deb

# Navigate to moveit project directory
# Apply this patch: (I have commit f91d87c329b14 of src/moveit_ros/visualization, might not be necessary in your checkout)
--- src/moveit_ros/visualization/CMakeLists.txt
+++ src/moveit_ros/visualization/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -86,4 +86,5 @@ install(FILES python/moveit_ros_visualization/moveit_joy.py DESTINATION ${CATKIN
 
 install(DIRECTORY icons DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
 
+find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
 add_rostest(test/moveit_joy.test)

# Enter moveit directory and compile and install moveit:
$ sudo -s
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ catkin_make_isolated --install -DMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/moveit/indigo -j2
```

---

Originally posted by [cmhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27017/cmhe/) with karma: 36 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) on 2016-12-26**:
I'm following these steps!
Thank you for your sharing :)

**Comment by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) on 2016-12-26**:
btw, I had some problems to follow your steps, So I decided to format my SD card and start all over it again
uhm... did you use Raspbian Lite or Pixel and do you think it matters?

Thank you very much

**Comment by [cmhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27017/cmhe/) on 2016-12-27**:
If I remember corrently I used raspbian lite. Since the project for which I did this, is finished quite a while ago and we ended up using ubuntu trusty for other reasons I can't really help any further. This was never intended to be a copy and paste solution, but should still work in general.

**Comment by [cmhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27017/cmhe/) on 2016-12-27**:
These where my notes for the more involved steps I toke while doing it, but since I fiddled around for a while, some parts might be missing or just obvious to me at that time.

**Comment by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) on 2016-12-28**:
thanks a lot!
i'm currently struggling to solve this problem using RPI3 Model B and it drives me crazy -.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the people who wants to install Moveit! on Raspberry pi 3 Model B with Jessie.

I spent almost whole week to install Moveit! on Jessie, I tried many other solutions but I failed.
However, I just found simple way to install Moveit!

Just

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit*
```

If you can't find any packages, just try

ps.

@renarded Sorry, I just saw it :/
I followed this link [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

And I did this steps:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse restricted

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit*
```

And check again.

---

Originally posted by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) with karma: 11 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) on 2017-01-06**:
Did you manage to launch moveit move_group after that ? I did the same as you and I get a segfault
Thread 1 "move_group" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. ( http://answers.ros.org/question/250606/moveit-move_group-segmentation-fault-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-with-raspberry-pi-3-ros-kinetic/ )

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-06**:
Are you sure you're on `armhf`? AFAIK there has been no binary built yet for `Jessie` for armhf for any ROS distro.

**Comment by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) on 2017-01-06**:
@renarded
Yeah it works well in Indigo. I don't know the packages are working in Kinetic :/
@130s
I'm not sure the packages are actually built for armhf.
But, I'm using in on my RPI3 Model B with Jessie.
When I type
`arch`
it says
`armv7l`

**Comment by [renarded](https://answers.ros.org/users/28606/renarded/) on 2017-01-10**:
@collin What steps or tutorial did you follow to get ROS indigo running on RPI3 with Raspbian Jessie ? Same as 130s, I've never heard of that before

**Comment by [collin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28896/collin/) on 2017-01-15**:
@renarded i updated my answers, check it and if you have more questions, just let me know.